# Unexpected end of file Bash(last line)

Tags: bash, shell

I tried almost all solutions suggested here but this very simple code of mine keeps showing this error

```
x=1
echo $x
while [$x -le 5];
do
echo $x
x=$(($x+1))
done
```

:

```
-sh-4.1$ sh test1.sh
1
test1.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

line 10 is one line after the "done" command. I know it has something to do with the spaces, but there aren't any spaces in my program.

Comment: I used the spaces. I feel it should work but i stil get the same error

Comment: Do you have DOS line endings in your script? try `cat -v test1.sh` and see if you're having ugly `^M` at the end of your lines.

Answer (score 3):

You must have spaces around `[ ]` to do the whole script working, so :

```
x=1
echo $x
while [ $x -le 5 ]; do
#      ^        ^
#    space    space
    echo $x
    x=$(($x+1))
done
```

or with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) arithmetic :

```
x=1
echo $x
while ((x < 5)); do
    echo $((x++))
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I just did the same thing. I copied and pasted the exact first snippet of yours, but it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Can I try anything else. I just can't get rid of this error.

Comment: Are you sure you are running bash and not another shell ? `echo $SHELL` will tell you

Comment: yes, when I do $SHELL, it gives me /bin/sh

Comment: @RAJKUMARPADILAM, `/bin/sh` is not bash.

Answer (score 0):

try put a header into the script

```
#!/bin/bash
```

this way linux will automatically interpret the script as a bash script.

Comment: I am using the header.                                        ##!/bin/bash -vx

Comment: @RAJKUMARPADILAM, `##!/bin/bash` is not `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - carriage-return characters in the file.

I was typing the script in Windows (text pad) and executing it on Linux.  The editor on Windows ends lines with `\r\n`; when running the script on Linux, the presence of `\r` was creating a problem.

Using `vi` as editor helped me resolve this issue.

Comment: So you ignored my comment?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment gniourf. Anyway thanks a lot. I could have saved some valuable time by seeing it.